# Regular Expression Error

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is the latest version of the regular expression I am using and it is throwing the error "Invalid Regular Expression."

Any foo with the formatting of the regular expression would be much appreciated!

Below is my code:

```
// This function gets all the text in browser
function getText() {
    return document.body.innerText;
}
var allText = getText(); // stores into browser text into variable

//regex set to rid text of all punctuaction, symbols, numbers, and excess  spaces
var matcher = new RegExp ("/(?<!\w)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\w)/", "g");

//cleanses text in browser of punctuation, symbols, numbers, and excess spaces
var newWords = allText.match(matcher);

//using a single space as the dividing tool, creates a list of all words
var Words=newWords.split(" ");
```

Comment: Use regex literal syntax or

When using RegEx constructor
**1.** you don't need the delimiter slashes
**2.** backslashes should be double escaped.

**Use** `new RegExp("(?<!\\w)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\\w)", "g");`

Comment: The regex is not doing what you think it is...

Comment: @Tushar just copied and pasted your recommendation and am still receiving the same error

Comment: JS doesn't support lookbehinds like `(?<!\w)`, try `\b` instead.

Comment: This is not a dupe of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705240/convert-string-into-regular-expression-in-javascript), it just has a lot of issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
//regex set to rid text of all punctuaction, symbols, numbers, and excess  spaces
var matcher = new RegExp ("/(?<!\w)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\w)/", "g");
//cleanses text in browser of punctuation, symbols, numbers, and excess spaces
var newWords = allText.match(matcher);
//using a single space as the dividing tool, creates a list of all words
var Words=newWords.split(" ");
```

Just use

```
var Words = allText.match(/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/g); // OR...
// var Words = allText.match(/\b[A-Z]+\b/ig);
```

This will get you all the "words" just consisting of ASCII letters as `String#match` together with a `/g`-based regex will fetch all substrings matching the regex (that matches 1 or more ASCII letters between word boundaries).

JS does not support lookbehind (i.e. `(?<!)` or `(?<=)` constructs), you need a word boundary `\b` here.

Note that you'd need something like `.replace(/\W+/g, ' ')` to *rid text of all punctuaction, symbols, numbers, and excess  spaces*, but it seems you just can rely on `.match(/\b[a-zA-Z]\b/g)`.